# Google Universal analytics API will continue to work after 1 July 2023 with the arrival of GA4?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, universal-analytics

Google has recently announced that Universal Analytics will be replaced by Google Analytics 4. From 1 July 2023 the standard Universal Analytics properties will stop processing data, extending the end date for Universal Analytics 360 properties a little further to 1 October 2023.

Will it still be possible to query data via API ?

Answer (score 1):

It should since it's listed in the ways to export data after July 1 2023 in [Google article on the matter](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11583528?hl=en)

Paragraph concerned:

> After July 1, 2023, you'll be able to access your previously processed
> data in your Universal Analytics property for at least six months. We
> know your data is important to you, and we strongly encourage you to
> export your historical reports during this time.

Export options at the bottom:

> How can I export data from my Universal Analytics property?
>
> There are currently several ways to export data from your Universal
> Analytics property.
>
> - Export individual reports into the following formats:
>
>   - CSV
>   - TSV
>   - TSV for Excel
>   - Excel (XLSX)
>   - Google Sheets
>   - PDF
> - Use the Google Analytics Reporting API to export data
> - Google Analytics 360 customers can also export to BigQuery
>
> We intend to offer more guidance on data export as we approach the
> date when Universal Analytics is no longer available.